# post text from files into a web page form using python

Tags: python, html, batch-file, post, input

I have a set of text files. I need to input them one after the other to a web server. I know how to input text using mechanize but have no idea how to extract text from files stored on computer and input them one after the other. In other words, say I have 10 files on my hard disk, I need to post text from one file, submit, then post another file and the process should go on until all the files are posted. Please help me with suggestions. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a for loop to iterate through your files. Then read the files and encode them into a POST request with urllib and urllib2. You need to change the url, filename pattern, and form fields accordingly.

```
url = "http://www.example.com/form"
import glob
import urllib
import urllib2
for filename in glob.glob("file*.txt"):
    filedata = open(filename).read()
    data = urllib.urlencode({'data' : filedata})
    urllib2.urlopen(url=url, data=data)
```

Comment: His Question didn't have much information. But nice generic answer.